# Create seaborn catplot with datetime in xaxis (python)

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I am using Python 3.7 in Anaconda's Juypter Notebook. I have data (stored in a csv file) that I would like to visualize using seaborn. My Y-axis is numerical data and my X-axis is the index of file, which are dates (e.g. 2019-01-07 15:00:00).

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
sns.catplot(x=data.index, y='Occupancy', hue='Match_Occupancy',
           sizes=(40, 40), alpha=.5, palette="muted",
            height=6, data=data)
```

What I get looks like this: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doYEh.jpg)

Everything works as intended except the x-axis. What can I do?

This is a sample of file.csv

> ```
>                  Occupancy   Match_Occupancy
> ```
>
> 2019-01-07 15:15:00       1           False
>   2019-01-07 15:30:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 15:45:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 16:00:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 16:15:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 16:30:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 16:45:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 17:00:00       0            True
>   2019-01-07 17:15:00       0            True

Comment: Each datapoint gets its own tick and label. The question is a bit, how would you like it to look instead? Is data equally spaced? In that case one could show only every nth label. Or more generally, are you sure you want a categorical plot with that many categories at all?

Comment: Please also publish file.csv or enough of it so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: I tried to attach the csv_file but that doesn't seem to be possible. So I tried to make it part of the question.